# recaptcha refresh button in django

Tags: javascript, django-forms, captcha, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha django form following [this tutorial](http://lobstertech.com/2008/aug/27/integrating_django_recaptcha/) . It works fine only the little  refresh button not working on the recaptcha image. Not sure what is going on.

the generated code of recaptcha

```
<script>var RecaptchaOptions = {theme : 'white'};</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6Lc6YLoSAAAAAAFKV5Y13hyLIl4y845XIUIQY-EN"></script> 

<noscript> 
  <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6Lc6YLoSAAAAAAFKV5Y13hyLIl4y845XIUIQY-EN" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br /> 
  <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea> 
  <input type='hidden' name='recaptcha_response_field' value='manual_challenge' /> 
</noscript>
```

Thanks

Comment: +1: nice, i was wondering how to do captchas!

Comment: You shouldn't post your API key in public forums!

Comment: i think public  key should be ok? The public key will be exposed to public anyway

Answer (score 1):

Never mind... It is my css causing the problem. If i remove my css it is working cool.